# send multiple files using bluetooth in android programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, data-transfer

I am working on an android application that will transfer multiple image files to another mobile device through bluetooth connection.

I have used following transfer method in android:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris=new ArrayList<Uri>();
String multifile[]={"/sdcard/aaa.txt","/sdcard/bbb.txt","/sdcard/ccc.txt"};
int len=multifile.length;
Intent Int=new Intent();
Int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
Int.setType("*/*");
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
File file=new File(multifile[i]);
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
}
Int.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Int);
```

This methos successfully transfered the files.But i have only nine images on android phone and then my application will go for another set of 9 images to be transfered,for that i have to call the above chooser wizard to send the files.
But i don’t want user to select option from chooser again n again.

Is there any way to send files through that option(bluetooth from wizard) silently(without user intervention) ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Instead of `putParcelableArrayListExtra` use `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris)`

It was asked a month ago so don't know how relevant it is for you, but may be it helps someone else. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        mul = fileSelectorList;
         Log.d("final",""+mul);
        int length = mul.size();

        //Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //mail_int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mail_int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    //mail_int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        mail_int.setType("image/*");
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            File file = new File(mul.get(i));
            uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));

        }

        mail_int.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivity(mail_int);
```